# Query hasMany relation with slug instead of id?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to query a category and all of its channels based on a slug.

**Works**

```
\App\Category::find(1)->channels()->get();
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
\App\Category::where('slug','animals')->channels()->get()
```

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Method Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder::channels does not exist.'

**Relationship on Category Model**

```
public function channels()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Channel::class,'category_id');
}
```

Comment: `\App\Category::where('slug','animals')->get()->channels`

Comment: Getting the same errors:
Exception with message 'Property [channels] does not exist on this collection instance.'

BadMethodCallException with message 'Method Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection::channels does not exist.'

Comment: try \App\Category::where('slug','animals')->with(['channels'])->get()

Comment: where does the field slug is ? in the channel or category ?

Comment: The slug field is on both the channel and category, but I am trying to get the category by slug. 

\App\Category::where('slug','animals')->with(['channels'])->get() ;

gets the channels associated with the category, but messes up my views and I don't think can be paginated by the channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you correctly have your *slug* field set-up in migration and model attributes (It looks like so from the *Exception* message).

Doing

`\App\Category::find(1)->channels()->get();`

is under the hood equivalent to

`\App\Category::where('category_id', 1)->first()->channels()->get();`

So what you are requiring, is to `get` the categories to actually execute the query and then be able to retrieve the channels from the hydrated model.

`\App\Category::where('slug', 'animals')->first()->channels()->get();`

should work as well as

`\App\Category::where('slug', 'animals')->first()->channels; // calling as attribute will perform the get() on the relationship`

Also take note that you may take advantage of other methods like `with()` for eager loading the relationship, `first()` to perform a get and ensure you take only one instance, and calling the relationship as attribute as shown above. Refer to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Comment: i think `\App\Category::where('category_id')->first()->channels()->get();` should be `\App\Category::where('id',1)->first()->channels()->get();`

Comment: @rkj thanks for pointing out the missing argument for the *id*. As per the example, from the relationship declaration I deduce the key is `category_id`, but of course could be any other defined by the dev.

Answer (score 0):

there are so many possible answer in your question .. be more specific .. but here's the list of sample queries that may help you ..

**GETTING ALL THE CATEGORY WITH ITS CHANNELS WHERE CATEGORY SLUG = ANIMAL**

```
Category::with(['channels'])->where('slug', 'animal')->get();
```

**GETTING ALL THE CATEGORY WITH ITS CHANNELS WHERE HAS A CHANNEL SLUG = ANIMAL**

```
Category::with(['channels'])->whereHas('channels'=>function($q){
    $q->where('slug','animal');
})->get();
```

**GETTING ALL THE CATEGORY WITH ONLY CHANNELS THAT HAS A SLUG = ANIMAL**

```
Category::with(['channels'=>function($q){
    $q->where('slug','animal');
}])->get();
```